# Access Terrain data more efficiently

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm developing an editor tool for terrains. I want to do some calculation every time the terrain is modified by user.

Currently I get heightmap with these:

```
TerrainData tData = SketchTerrain.terrainData;
int resolution = tData.heightmapResolution - 1;
float[,] heights = tData.GetHeights(0, 0, resolution, resolution);
```

And then I have to check every float in the array to see if there are any changes. This works but it's slow and creates garbage and I have to do it in a fraction of a second (like 4 times per second). I also have to do it for splats too. This puts too much pressure on the CPU and results in frame rate drop.

So is there an alternative?